# Unable to uninstall pyspark from Azure pipeline. Uninstallation is stuck

Tags: pyspark, azure-devops, pip

I have a test pipeline in Azure Devops. In the pipeline, I want to uninstall pyspark module. I do it with `pip uninstall pyspark`. Below is the pipeline

```
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: 'QA_Pipeline'
  timeoutInMinutes: 300
  pool: vmss-deep-dev-pool-002
  
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'

  - script:  |
       pip install --upgrade  --force-reinstall pip setuptools wheel
       pip uninstall pyarrow
       pip uninstall pyspark
       pip install -I azure-cli==2.18.0 
       pip install -I databricks-connect==9.1.30
    displayName: 'Install modules'
  ...
  ...
```

When I execute this pipeline, the pyspark installation is found but the uninstallation never finishes.
Below is the stacktrace

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-67.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.38.4
    Uninstalling wheel-0.38.4:
      Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.38.4
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 67.0.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-67.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-67.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0
    Uninstalling pip-23.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0
Successfully installed pip-23.0 setuptools-67.0.0 wheel-0.38.4
WARNING: Skipping pyarrow as it is not installed.
Found existing installation: pyspark 3.3.1
Uninstalling pyspark-3.3.1:
Would remove:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/beeline
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/beeline.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/docker-image-tool.sh
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/find-spark-home
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/find-spark-home.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/find_spark_home.py
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/load-spark-env.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/load-spark-env.sh
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/pyspark
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/pyspark.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/pyspark2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/run-example
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/run-example.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-class
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-class.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-class2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-shell
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-shell.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-shell2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-sql
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-sql.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-sql2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-submit
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-submit.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/spark-submit2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/sparkR
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/sparkR.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/bin/sparkR2.cmd
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark-3.3.1.dist-info/*
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.16/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/*
```

It has been around 4 hours and I do not see any progress. I tried stopping the job and restarting but it does not help. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip uninstall -y pyspark` seems to do the trick. It works now